# Unable to add excel add-in for all users

Tags: wix, windows-installer, excel-addins

We have an application which shows up as an Excel ribbon.

We have installed the application in our test environment through administrator login. We are trying to make a per machine installation.(Please note that in production environment, the installation will be through system account). 
When we login as user to the same PC, we don't see the excel addin in the Excel ribbons. We don't see the addins anywhere in the list of addins as well.

We have tried using Active setup,Userstat,setting the values of properties as ALLUSERS=1, RegisterForAllUsers= True, InstallScope= perMachine, InstallAllUsers = Everyone, RunActionsAsInvoker = True . Also the privileges has been changed from user to admin in all the cutom actions and in manifest file as well. All these changes where made as we understood that the application used to package is Addin express and so the msi creation with privileges as admin is possible.

Unfortunately none of these changes seems to help us.

What we would need is an msi which we can install on per machine basis.

Comment: We are Installing the package in C:\Users\Public\Documents folder which is accessible for all Users and use InstallShield to do packaging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the situation mentioned in the question, we had tried a lot of options and finally following approach works for us:-

Create a package which would place a powershell shortcut in the startup folder.
The shortcut would in turn call or execute a powershell script.

The powershell script would 
 1. check if the registry key for that particular add-in is available in HKCU.
    We had our registry key as "**HKCU\Software\Manufacturer Name\Product Name**"  which in turn had a string value "**Installed**".

2. If the registry key is not available for the user, then install the package with tranform.

   3.If the registry is already available, then script doesn't make any change.

The package is installed as an Admin and once the user logs in, then automatically the cmd file is executed and the add-in is installed.

Since this was the first version of the product, we didn't have to handle version compatibility.